# How to do pagination while sorting by a score?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am doing pagination in javascript with startAt([uniqueId]) and orderBy("uniqueId"); using this unqiue id makes it so it doesn't skip documents. But, I want to sort the documents by another field "score" when I display them in a UITableView. I can't do startAt([score]) and orderBy("score") because it will skip docs that have the same score. How can I do this? Note: Getting the first x documents from the database and then sorting them on the client will not work because this will not completely sort the entire UITableView correctly because it is just like: [sorted arr] + [sorted arr] + .. and not just one big sorted array (I am using an array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question just 10 minutes after posting. I set my score field to be equal to the `numerial score + unique id` this way each user has a unique score and no skipping will occur. To ensure everything comes back in the correct order, I made sure all the numerical scores had the same number of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Use your uniqueId like this: `uniqueId = score + randomGeneratedId`. This will allow you to order your result by `score` and still dont skip through documents that have the same `score` since the `randomGeneratedId` part.